# sqlloader: how to use substr in when-clause correctly?

Tags: oracle11g, sql-loader

I'm having a problem that I thought to be rather common, but trying to look it up in the "Oracle Database 10g2 Utilities_b14215.pdf" didn't help. After that I've surfed through numerous threads but no luck so far.

I'm having a tab-delimited file (x'09') e. g. name, userid, persnr. The values for the userids begin with either `P`, `R` or `T` e. g. P2198, P2199, R7288, T1229.

I want to load only the records with userids beginning with `P`.

Isolating a single record with a controlfile like this works splendidly:

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA
INFILE UserlistLoader.dat
APPEND
INTO TABLE Z_USERLIST
WHEN USERID = 'P2198'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY x'09'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(name, userid, persnr)
```

But every attempt at using SUBSTR in the when-clause fails.

This:

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA
INFILE UserlistLoader.dat
APPEND
INTO TABLE Z_USERLIST
WHEN SUBSTR(USERID, 1, 1) = 'P'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY x'09'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(name, userid, persnr)
```

ends in an SQL*Loader-350: Syntax-Error.

This

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA
INFILE UserlistLoader.dat
APPEND
INTO TABLE Z_USERLIST
WHEN "SUBSTR(:USERID, 1, 1)" = 'P'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY x'09'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(name, userid, persnr)
```

ends in an SQL*Loader-403: Referenced column USERID not present in table Z_USERLIST.

But IT IS PRESENT - as the first example proves. I've found that the column should be preceded by `:` but that obviously isn't the issue.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From [SQL Loader docs](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-81C21533-7B7F-4DE8-8C15-1FDD8D31B581.htm#SUTIL1115) the left-hand side of a `WHEN` condition can only be a full field name e.g. `USERID` or a position spec e.g. `(3:5)`.

The docs aren't very clear though on what is allowed - e.g. can `LIKE` be used as the operator?

```
USERID LIKE 'P%'
```

I strongly suspect it can't though.

Comment: I'm not very surprised, SQL Loader isn't SQL or PL/SQL.  So looks like you simply cannot do what you want, except by loading into a staging table first and then extracting the rows you want from that.

Answer (score 0):

I would load the entire file into a staging table that matches the file layout, then run a procedure that inserts the rows you want from there into the production table.  That is a more common way to handle loads with criteria like this without having to edit source data.

If you can preprocess the source file, move the userid to the first field or copy the first letter of the userid to it's own field and construct the WHEN like this so sqlldr looks at the first position (this will cause sqlldr to return non-zero though, as not all rows meet WHEN clause criteria):

```
WHEN (1) = 'P'
```